# HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString incorrectly decodes §

Tags: c#, unicode, query-string, urlencode

I have a query string which contains the character §, for example `/search?q=5§2`. This should be encoded as `/search?q=5%c2%a72`, but `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString()` gives me `q=5%u00a72`. For some reason the `%c2` is lost.

Comment: Looks like `%u00a7` is the UTF-16 code point for your character. [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Encoding is ok, you can read more details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ("Non-standard implementations" part)

To not think about it you can just use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` to obtain real `q=5§2` string regardless used encoding.